# Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemProperty', u'Type mismatch) when reading Windows registry on Python 

Tags: python

What program could I use to get a list of installed software using Python for cross platform or at least Windows or Mac? Please check the code which i googled, but am getting some errors. I am using Python 2.7, win 7 64 bit, eclipse

```
import StringIO
import traceback    
import wmi
from _winreg import (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 
                     OpenKey, EnumValue, QueryValueEx)

softFile = open('softLog.log', 'w')
errorLog = open('errors.log', 'w')

r = wmi.Registry ()
result, names = r.EnumKey (hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

softFile.write('These subkeys are found under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"\n\n')
errorLog.write("Errors\n\n")
separator = "*" * 80
keyPath = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

for subkey in names:
    try:
        softFile.write(separator + '\n\n')
        path = keyPath + "\\" + subkey
        key = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS) 
        try:
            temp = QueryValueEx(key, 'DisplayName')
            display = str(temp[0])
            softFile.write('Display Name: ' + display + '\nRegkey: ' + subkey + '\n')
        except:
            softFile.write('Regkey: ' + subkey + '\n')

    except:
        fp = StringIO.StringIO()
        traceback.print_exc(file=fp)
        errorMessage = fp.getvalue()
        error = 'Error for ' + key + '. Message follows:\n' + errorMessage
        errorLog.write(error)
        errorLog.write("\n\n")

softFile.close()/* files are empty*/
errorLog.close()
```

Error displayed in console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\EclipseWorkspace\Aug28th2012\PythonDevelopment\src\TestClass\Hii.py", line 21, in <module>
    result, names = r.EnumKey (hDefKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sSubKeyName=r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 431, in __call__
    handle_com_error ()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
wmi.x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemProperty', u'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. In general, requests for code are usually poorly received unless some prior effort is demonstrated. Can you post any code you've written so far that we can help you with? Have you tried Googling, and if so, what kinds of information have you found?

Comment: What do you mean by installed software? Applications in Installed Programs (for Windows) or Applications (for Macs)? Are you including command-line commands?

Answer (score 0):

Installed software concept is not well-defined, as on Windows the application installation process is free form on non-closed platforms (iOS, Android).

Possible options

- Read Installed applications using Windows API
- List folders in `C:\Program Files`
- On OSX "installed application" is the content of the folder `/Applications`

If you want to check for a specific application then read its related installation entry (application specific) from Windows registry.

Comment: I want to write the code to chk for installations

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329073/executing-wmi-registry-enumkey-gives-type-mismatch-error/40363864#40363864

Basically, it seems like an issue with the _winreg constants and 64 bit python.

Comment: Just a heads up, once you hit 50 rep on the site, posting just a link to an answer elsewhere would be more appropriate as a comment.  As an answer post, it would be better self-contained, replicating the answer here.